# numpy matrices replacing zeroes

Tags: numpy, matrix, replace, sum

Let's say I have this matrix:

```
mx1 = np.matrix([[2,0,9],[0,5,8],[1,2,0]])

[[2 0 9]
 [0 5 8]
 [1 2 0]]
```

I would like to replace only the 0 values with the values coming from another matrix (same dimensions):

```
mx2 = np.matrix([[5,6,2],[3,3,7],[0,1,6]])

[[5 6 2]
 [3 3 7]
 [0 1 6]]
```

The resulting matrix should be:

```
[[2 6 9]
 [3 5 8]
 [1 2 6]]
```

No loops please.
Ideas?

Comment: What have you already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The only way I have done it is by iterating over rows and columns with an If condition, but I am working with a lot of big matrices and loops are not an options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-liner using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(mx1 == 0, mx2, m1)
```

Bookmark those docs, it'll save you downvotes.